# homomorphism inducing monomorphism on some quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism such that $f_* :G_{ab}\rightarrow H_{ab}$ is an isomorphism and that $f_* : H_2(G)\rightarrow H_2(H)$ is an epimorphism.

Question is to prove that this induced a monomorphism $$f:\frac{G}{\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}G_n}\rightarrow \frac{H}{\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}H_n}$$

Define the abelianization of a group $G$ to be the quotient group $G_{ab} := G/[G,G]$, where $[G,G]$ is the [commutator subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup). $G_n$ is the lower central series defined inductively as
 $G_1=[G,G]; G_{n+1}=[G,G_n]$

I see that $f(G_n)\subset H_n$ so we have induced map $f: G/G_n\rightarrow H/H_n$ and for similar reasons we have well defined map

$$f:\frac{G}{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n}\rightarrow \frac{H}{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n}$$

Now the question is how do you show that this is a monomorphism..

Let $[x]\in \frac{G}{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n}$ such that $[f(x)]=0\in \frac{H}{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n}$ i.e., $f(x)\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n$

As $f(x)\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n$ we have in particular $f(x)\in H_1$.

As $f_* : G/[G,G]\rightarrow H/[H,H]$ is an isomorphism and $f(x)\in [H,H]$ we have $x\in [G,G]$

So, there is some hope.. If $f(x)\in H_1 $ we have $x\in G_1$...

As $f(x)\in H_2=[H,H_1]$.. Taking for granted all better possibilities we have $f(x)=h(aba^{-1}b^{-1})h^{-1}(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}$... I am not sure where to go from this...

I am not sure how to use other details of that isomorphism to conclude $x\in G_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Please suggest something...

Comment: This can't be right! We could have $H = G/[G,G]$ for example.

Comment: i am not sure... For reference this is an exercise from A course in homological algebra by hilton stammbach chapter 6, exercise 9.1... @DerekHolt

Comment: But as it stands it is clearly wrong! Are you sure you haven't missed out a hypothesis?

Comment: I intentionally did not write one hypothesis as i was sure that this is not related.. I have added it now.. please check it.. @DerekHolt

Comment: Ah right! That makes it harder! It's late at night here, so I'll have to leave it for today.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Alright... Thank you :) Please have a look at this tomorrow...

Comment: What is $H_2$? Homology with coefficients in?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal : I am sorry.. It is not mentioned.. Probably from some arbitrary $G$ module $B$..

Comment: It probably means $H_2(G,{\mathbb Z})$, which is the Schur Multiplier of $G$. I am still thinking about the problem, but haven't had any time today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Theorem 9.1 (Chap. VI) in Hilton-Stammbach's A Course in Homological Algebra, $f$ induces for each $n$ an isomrphism $$f_n: G/G_n \to H/H_n.$$

Now let $x\in G$ represent an element from the kernel of $G/\bigcap_nG_n \to H/\bigcap_n H_n$. Hence $f(x)\in \bigcap_nH_n\subseteq H_n$. In particular $f_n(\bar{x})=\bar{1}$ and, by the theorem, $\bar{x}=\bar{1}\in G/G_n$. Thus $x\in G_n$. This holds for all $n$, so $x \in \bigcap_nG_n$ and we are done.

Comment: How did i miss this... thank you so much.. I was reading again and again what is assumed and i have neglected what is proved in that theorem... Actually i did not study  that section.. I was thinking this would be some simple group theory question... So with out studying that section i tried it.. Now i realize :D

Comment: I'm glad it helped. But I wonder if the theorem has any useful applications. Perhaps someone can tell about such.

Comment: I hope some one would do that :)